# Eclipse get Java class name for Maven configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to set up a Maven exec.  In order to do this I need to set the mainClass as a parameter.  I have the following class, but I can't figure out what the name of it is:
[image]

How do I get the class name of this class (MusicManiac)?

Comment: check the properties of the class

Comment: have you tried `musicmaniac.MusicManic`?

Comment: `{package.name}`.`{simple-class-name}` => `musicmaniac.MusicManic`

Comment: I tried musicmaniac.MusicManiac but I get the following error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: musicmaniac.MusicManiac`

Comment: do you have the method `public static void main(String[] args)` in your class ?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Yes I do.  The project runs fine if I do a regular run in Eclipse also.  It only has problems when I do the Maven run.

Comment: what is your maven command exactly ?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I'm using a plugin for Eclipse (M2Eclipse) that generates the commands automatically and I don't know how to view them.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I can't tell if using the plugin is worth it. I feel like I should be able to see the commands. Do you recommend using the plugin or not?